# Understand android.graphics.Camera object in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, augmented-reality, graphics2d

I am developing an Android AR app for my bachelor's Thesis.

I found the Camera class in package **android.graphics** (sdk link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) and I didn't understand what the method *dotWithNormal()*?

Do you have any tutorial in which this object is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very useful for manipulating the `Matrix` attached to a `Canvas`, in particular for doing clever 3D effects without OpenGL.

[This 3D flip effect uses it](http://code.google.com/p/android-flip3d/), IIRC.